# Как прочитать тег [CDATA] из XML-файла посредством PHP?

Tags: php, xml

Новостная компания обновила движок новостного rss-канала.
Теперь там используется `CDATA`.
Как эту `CDATA` прочесть?
[сам файл rss - смотреть через viewcode](https://zapad24.ru/minusinsk/rss.xml)
— -
**UPD:**
Через `simplexml_load_file($url, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA)` добился следующего:

```
[19] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [title] => В Канске вернувшийся из мест заключения отец устроил своим детям урок "воспитания"
                            [pubDate] => Wed, 01 Mar 2023 14:22:36 +0700
                            [category] => Канск

                            [yandex:full-text] => В Канске у неоднократно судимого местного жителя изъяты дети....<br>
                        )
```

Данная CDATA раскрылась. Но я так и не смог вытащить данные из  [yandex:full-text].
Старый код работающий без CDATA c яндекс (тегом yandex:full-text) не смог. $full_text=$item->children('yandex',true);

Comment: Ссылка не рабочая. Кроме того, хотелось бы уточнить какими средствами Вы планируете читать этот `rss` (язык программирования, библиотека и т.д.)?

Comment: @Streletz php ("2 символа нужно", это так просит StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 2):

Для разбора RSS-файла удобно воспользоваться функцией `simplexml_load_file()`, для того, чтобы получить доступ к элементам внутри `<![CDATA[`, ей следует передать в качестве третьего параметра константу `LIBXML_NOCDATA`, которая предписывает преобразовывать эти элементы в текст

```
<?php
$url = 'http://krsk.sibnovosti.ru/news/rss_all.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
```

Comment: Получил строки: "[yandex:full-text] => В Канске у неоднократно судимого местного жителя изъяты дети...."
Но расковырять эту строку так и не получается.